# Plotly bar plot overlay colors getting mixed

Tags: python, plot, plotly, bar-chart, visualization

I have a bar plot (python plotly) with two traces in blue and yellow (as shown by the legend), using the `barmode='overlay'` layout setting. But however when displaying the figure, these two colors get 'mixed' and it ends up being a dark purple color, which is confusing to the user as the legend does not show this mixed color. Is there any way to not mix the original colors with `barmode='overlay'`?

[image]

Comment: Please add a minimum code for your problem to be able to help you.

Comment: This is bound to happen with 'overlay' as the yellow color is mixed with the blue where they overlap. It might be better to use 'stack' or 'group' to be able to more easily identify the groups and their actual sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You can prohibit the colors being mixed by setting `opacity=1`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame(data={"total": [10, 8, 9], "part": [5, 8, 8]}, index=["group1", "group2", "group3"])
px.bar(df, barmode="overlay", opacity=1)
```

[Barplot with 3 groups and 2 colors overlaying each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgPu9.png)

I did not find a way however to change to colors of the legend only.